# Export a writable sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there a way to export a writable database? I need to use the database I have exported from the phone in a Visual Studio app as part of the system. Its bad, I know, but its the only I could do my project. This is the code i use to export the database from the `SQLiteImporterExporter` library

```
public void exportDataBase(String path) {
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    try {
        String inFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myInput = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
        String outFileName = path + DB_NAME;
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        if (exportListener != null)
            exportListener.onSuccess("Successfully Exported");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (exportListener != null)
            exportListener.onFailure(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (exportListener != null)
                exportListener.onFailure(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the sqlite binding you're using support the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html), which is the best way to copy a live in-use db? Or can you run the sqlite3 shell on the database in android and use its `.backup` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to export a writable database?

From your code, assuming that it's working, then that's what you are doing. It is also assumed that you are ensuring that the database is not in-use elsewhere and that it has been closed.

That is, an SQLite database is a single file, copy that file and you can then use that database anywhere where you have SQLite. The writable/readable concept (i.e. `getWritableDatabase` v `getReadableDatabase`) is one of the more common mis-conceptions. The latter will in most cases get a writable database, it will only return a read only database if the database cannot be written too e.g. (full disk). As per :-

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.

[getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase())

**Exceptions/considerations would be :-**

- If the database were encrypted, in which case you would use the encryption code/extension along with the key.
- If you use in-memory/temporary tables, in this case AND if you needed these in-memory/temporary tables, you could either create a copy database but changing in-memory/temporary to be permanent.

  - SQLite does have a backup API, which does this. However, I don't believe that the SQLite API in Android implements the backup API though (so it could well be a bigger pain to try utilising it, than implementing the copy method).
- being on Android, there will be an additional table in the database named **android_metadata**, this simply stores the locale and can be ignored elsewhere.

Comment: I literally forgot to close the database before exporting